# Load image or text in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I want to make a simple web app using R SHiny where I load a image from my harddrive by giving the path and displaying it on my webpage when a button is clicked.

I started by doing that for text, for example displaying the path, but my button does not react when I click(I mean to say it doesnt print the message).

server.R:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  dt<-reactive({
  output$text1 <- renderText({ 
  paste("You have selected", input$obs)
   })
  }) 
})
```

ui.R:

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Fruits and vegetables!"),
  sidebarPanel(
    helpText("What do you see below?"),
    #imageOutput(outputId="images/1.png")
    numericInput("obs", "Number of observations to view:", 10),
    actionButton("get", "Get")
),
  mainPanel(textOutput("text1"))
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reactives, you must wrap the code that's using your inputs in a `reactive` block, but you must set the `output` values outside of it. In this case, your example should be

```
 shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
   headerPanel("Fruits and vegetables!"),
   sidebarPanel(
     helpText("What do you see below?"),
     #imageOutput(outputId="images/1.png")
     numericInput("obs", "Number of observations to view:", 10),
     actionButton("get", "Get")
   ),
   mainPanel(textOutput("text"))
 ))
```

---

```
 shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
   dt <- reactive({
     paste("You have selected", input$obs)
   })
   output$text <- renderText({ dt() })
 })
```

To use the `imageOutput` dynamically, you should provide more information about how you want the image URL to be selected from the input.

Comment: I see. However what this code does is only updating the variable on the fly, not when the button "get" is pressed. How to delay the action until the button is pressed?

Comment: I figured out it is "submit button" that needs to be present, not action! What are action buttons used for?

Comment: I am sorry for the many comments. About the image URL, the logic in my R script will select images and display them on the page. I essentially need to feed a pathname from my local computer to it.